# Get the list of ordered products from multiple scanner inputs

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class PointOfSale extends ProductDisplay
{   
    public PointOfSale()
    {   System.out.print("\nPurchase Item(y/n)?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(line)){
        OpenOrder();
            }
    }
    //=============================================
    public void OpenOrder() // New Order
    {  
        ArrayList<String> ProductList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ProductList.add("A001");   
        ProductList.add("A002");
        ProductList.add("A003");    
        ProductList.add("A004");
        ProductList.add("A005");
        System.out.print("Select Product Code:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String code = sc.next();
        if(ProductList.contains(code))
        { 
        product.getProduct(code);
          EnterQuantity();      
         }
        else System.out.print("Product Code is Invalid\n"); 
        System.exit(0);}
    //==============================================
    public void EnterQuantity()  //Entering Quantity
    {
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int quantity = sc.nextInt();
            double amount = quantity * product.getPrice();
            System.out.print("Amount: " + amount);

            //add new item
            System.out.print("\nAdd Item(y/n)?");  
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String add = sc2.nextLine();

            if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(add)){
                OpenOrder();
                    }
            else {
                DisplayOrder();

            }



        }
        catch (InputMismatchException nfe)
            {System.out.print("\nInvalid Entry: Input must be a Number.\n"); System.exit(0);}
    }


    public void DisplayOrder()  //Displaying order information
    {







    }




    // Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   new PointOfSale(); }
}
```

as you can see you can purchase orders in a neverending loop. but those orders arent stored so i cant call them. cause if you stop ordering, there should be a receipt of some sort. how can i store these multiple orders and display them on DisplayORder

Comment: You seem to have no basic java knowledge. I'll add an example for you.

Comment: You should respon to the answers. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a `List<String> productsOrdered = null;` and initialize it in your constructor

```
if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(line)){
            productsOrdered = new ArrayList<String>();
        OpenOrder();
            }
```

so whenever you are getting a new order it will be reinitialized.

Now you can update this list either in at the time when user is selecting prod code or in the EnterQuantity method because from here you can hold the quantity as well (you just need a simple change in this method as public void EnterQuantity(String code) .. pass the code value while calling EnterQuantity).

Now add these values in the list.

```
productsOrdered.add(code+"-"+quantity);
```

You can display these orders in the DisplayOrder method as

```
for(String prodOrdered : productsOrdered){
            System.out.println(prodOrdered);
        }
```

Comment: What about price? He should use Object oriented approach.

Comment: Ya definitely Object oriented is the best way in which he can implement this. I was sharing if he doesn't want to make much changes in the existing code and wants easiest way to implement this. But yes if you implement creating another class Order and having fields like code, quantity and price in it that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

I tired to run your code and the answer looks simple.

You should create a new Class called 'Order' (probably) which can store the added product and quantity into an Arraylist in that class.

Add function to add the Product and quantity to it.
Another function to print the contents for display.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new POJO class with two fields in it. The Product Code and the quantity. Everytime you fetch the product code and the quantity, create an instance of the POJO class with the user entered values and add it to a list. In the display method, fetch each instance of the class from your list and display the contents.